# What is wrong with this call to Google Analytics __utm.gif?

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to use PHP to fire hits at Google to track newsletter opens and clickthroughs.  I want to use the same technique for both clickthroughs and opens since the clickthroughs will go to sites outside of my own control - I want to be able to report on the clickthrough rates of the newsletters regardless of where the clicks go to. I was thinking of trying `code.google.com/p/php-ga/` but there is little in the way of example code/support docs to start with so I am hesitant.

Here is my url to `__utm.gif` broken up over the lines for clarity:

> utm.gif?utmac=MO-xxx31982-1">http://www.google-analytics.com/_utm.gif?utmac=MO-xxx31982-1
>
> &utmhn=myfake.com
>
> &utmcc=_*utma%3D7042858245.1436153422.1214501708.1340117181.1340117181.1%3B%2B*_utmz%3D1.1340117181.1.1.utmcsr%3D%28direct%29%7Cutmccn%3D%28direct%29%7Cutmcmd%3D%28none%29%3B
>
> &utmwv=1
>
> &utmr=click
>
> &utm_source=Emails
>
> &utm_medium=Newsletter
>
> &utm_campaign=tet+2012-06-19+10%3A41%3A30
>
> &utmp=%2FMYZZ%2FNEWSLETTERS
>
> &uservar=16430

Does the `utmhn` need to be a legit URL or one associated with the account?  What about `utmr`?  I was using that to contain 'click' or 'open' so I could differentiate.

When I click a link in the newsletter I get the expected pixel image returned so Google is getting something anyway even if ignoring my querystring.  In my Google Analytics account where should I see the data relating the the `__utm.gif` hits? So far I see none when using this technique.

P.S. I got this technique [from here](http://www.kontain.com/karlstanton/entries/47993/tracking-your-email-campaigns/)

Follow up:
I changed a few things and my url now looks like so:

> utm.gif?utmwv=1">http://www.google-analytics.com/_utm.gif?utmwv=1
>
> &utmn=8391432847
>
> &utmsr=click
>
> &utmsc=-
>
> &utmul=-
>
> &utmje=0
>
> &utmfl=-
>
> &utmdt=-
>
> &utmhn=myfake.com
>
> &utm_source=my_newsletter
>
> &utm_medium=Emails
>
> &utm_campaign=tet 2012-06-19 10:41:30
>
> &utmr=my_newsletter
>
> &utmp=images/google/click
>
> &utmac=MO-xxx31982-1
>
> &utmcc=_*utma%3D24820632.1925394567.1340121629.1340121629.1340121629.2%3B%2B*_utmb%3D24820632%3B%2B_*utmc%3D24820632%3B%2B*_utmz%3D24820632.1340121629.2.2.utmccn%3D(direct)%7Cutmcsr%3D(direct)%7Cutmcmd%3D(none)%3B%2B__utmv%3D24820632.6430%3B

and nothing happens except when I paste that link into my browser then Google gets it,  so why does it not work when called from the PHP line `$handle = fopen ($urchinUrl1, "r");`?

Comment: Whose support?  php-ga or googles?

Comment: Google. It's their service so they should be able to answer questions about it.

Comment: nothing yet,  but notice the extra part I added, the url works from the browser but not from the php line $handle = fopen ($urchinUrl1, "r");  why work for one but not the other?

Comment: Google Support won't help because this is not a supported use case. They provide some mobile libraries for server side tracking but any change to that library is unsupported code. php-ga builds on top of the php version of the mobile library but it's not official or supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, nevermind.  I changed my app around so the utm.gif is just included in the email and in a redirect page rather than called from the script.  Should have done it that way but got caught up in the fancier idea of calling the url from php.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question is over a year old...the GA measurement protocol can be used to send hits back to GA for newsletter opens and clickthroughs.

To answer your initial question, it looks like you're missing the utmhid and utmn parameters.